# Codingbat roundsum Logic explanation

Tags: python, python-3.x, logic

Hello I am doing the round sum exercise in Python and I dont really understand the logic behind the exercise. here is the description of the exercise:

> For this problem, we'll round an int value up to the next multiple of 10 if its rightmost digit is 5 or more, so 15 rounds up to 20. Alternately, round down to the previous multiple of 10 if its rightmost digit is less than 5, so 12 rounds down to 10. Given 3 ints, a b c, return the sum of their rounded values. To avoid code repetition, write a separate helper "def round10(num):" and call it 3 times. Write the helper entirely below and at the same indent level as round_sum().

And Here is the code:

```
def round_sum(a, b, c):

  def round10(n):
    return (n+5)/10*10 
    
  return round10(a) + round10(b) + round10(c)
```

expected output:
round_sum(16, 17, 18) → 60
I ran the code on coding bat and it worked how it is supposed to, but I dont understand the logic of the round10 method, also, when I ran the code in my computer not in the coding bat site the output was 66.0

Comment: Be careful with `/` division, which in Python can return a float. If you do `5/4`, the answer is `1.25` not `1`. If you want to perform the integer division, you should use `//`. Therefore you can fix the `round10()` function by using `return (n+5)//10*10`

Comment: that was a typo, thanks for the correction but I dont really understand the logic on how that method actually rounds up or down @JacobK

Comment: So the `(n+5)` part in `(n+5)//10*10` allows for the `//10` part to round to the number correctly. For example, if `n=13`, `n+5` equals 18, so when you integer divide by 10 `//10` the answer is 1. As you can see 1.8 is rounded down to 1, meaning that the multiple of 10 rounding for 13 is 10 not 20. Basically if the rightmost digit is >= 5, the `//10` result is ONE greater than the second rightmost digit. If the rightmost digit <5, then the `//10` result is the SAME as the second rightmost digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remember that in python3 the / operator divides with decimals but the // operator doesn't return the values following the comma so if n = 12.

```
12 + 5 = 17 // 10 = 1 * 10 -> 10
```

Thats how it rounds up or down. You can also test it with 18 so we see how it rounds up.

```
18 + 5 = 23 // 10 = 2 * 10 -> 20
```